# ng build --prod is not working properly? how to check this?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have one angular cli application. If i run that using `ng serve` command, it works fine.

Instead of using `ng serve`, i used `ng build --prod`. it throws following script error:

screenshot:

[image]

**i want to check this application in production mode.**

> Here i have attached my code:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups';
import { EmitType } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title="test";
  @ViewChild('ejDialog') ejDialog: DialogComponent;
  // Create element reference for dialog target element.
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;
  // The Dialog shows within the target element.
  public targetElement: HTMLElement;

  //To get all element of the dialog component after component get initialized.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initilaizeTarget();
  }

  // Initialize the Dialog component target element.
  public initilaizeTarget: EmitType<object> = () => {
    this.targetElement = this.container.nativeElement.parentElement;
  }

  // Hide the Dialog when click the footer button.
  public hideDialog: EmitType<object> = () => {
      this.ejDialog.hide();
  }
  // Sample level code to handle the button click action
  public onOpenDialog = function(event:any): void {
      // Call the show method to open the Dialog
      this.ejDialog.show();
  }
  //Animation options
  public animationSettings: Object = { effect: 'Zoom', duration: 400, delay: 0 };
  // Enables the footer buttons
  public buttons: Object = [
      {
          'click': this.hideDialog.bind(this),buttonModel:{ content:'OK', isPrimary: true }
      },
      {
          'click': this.hideDialog.bind(this),buttonModel:{ content:'Cancel' }
      }
  ];
}
```

> Html file:

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Dialog Component</h2>

<button class="e-control e-btn" style="position: absolute;" id="targetButton" (click)="onOpenDialog($event)">Open Dialog</button>
<div #container class='root-container'></div>
  <ejs-dialog id='dialog' #ejDialog header='Dialog' content='Dialog enabled with Zoom effect' [target]='targetElement'
  [animationSettings]='animationSettings' width='250px' [buttons]='buttons'>
  </ejs-dialog>
```

if i use the following command, it is working fine: What is the problem?

`ng build --prod --no-build-optimizer`

Comment: Why do you open html files? you should use server copy build folder and use it.

Comment: i want production mode of my application, so i use that command.

Comment: Its not about command, its about server. you need server to serve that files. you are using file system to access the file. Look at your browser URL.

Comment: okay, then how will you run production mode of application

Comment: did you try ng serve --prod? are you getting the same error. You can also try ng build --prod --watch

Comment: hi @SureshKumarAriya, if i use this cmd it is working "ng build --prod --no-build-optimizer". but my question is why an error occur when using ng build --prod

Comment: Can you take a look at this? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10658 It might be the same problem you have.

Comment: @kumaresan_sd, "All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking, while --prod builds also run limited dead code elimination via UglifyJS". most probably you has code (e.g. some .ts) that not use. (tree.shaking: , https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Comment: hi @wannadream, thanks i got clear view now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ng serve --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=true
```

Answer (score 5):

In new version you need to use $ ng build --configuration production

Answer (score 2):

`ng build --prod` is only using for hosting purposes only. Use `DIST` folder and take those contents and publish or host

`ng serve` is used for compiling and testing purposes

Comment: Does taking the dist folder uses the `production env` ?